# What is the exact behavior of Windows' SetEvent?

Tags: c++, windows, synchronization

I have an auto-reset event object, and there is one thread waiting on it. If now I call SetEvent, can it be guaranteed that the event object is nonsignaled when SetEvent has returned?

I have two threads that run in a A-B-A-B-... way. As soon as A wakes up B, A will start waiting for B. If I can wait on the same event object right after signaled it, well... I can save one event object.

If you ask why I don't just use one single thread, they are in different processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event becomes unsignaled when the waiter is released. There is no guarantee that the waiter will be released before the call to `SetEvent` returns.

Comment: OK, so what unsignals the event?  Can't be the event setter thread because it is possible that the waiter is not released when the SetEvent() returns and the event becomes unsignaled when the waiter is released.  Can't be the waiter thread because if it's not released it cannot run.

Comment: Oh, right.  I always thought that there was something odd about those event thingies...

Comment: Indeed, if you write a test program that tries to do it with a single event, you'll find that you often see a thread consuming its own signal (rather than letting the other thread consume it).

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. By that time, another thread may have signaled it and, if there is no thread waiting, it will remain set.  In the case of just two threads, then maybe you will be OK.

Why are you even bohering with such an 'optimization'. Using two events will be easier to debug.

Multiple threads, inter-thread and inter-process comms is difficult enough as it is.  You should not add more complication.

Comment: More or less it is just curiosity, since the kernel seems actually working this way. But I wonder if it is enforced by something more than the implementation.

Comment: The overall behavior of Windows events seems to be a bit weird.  @Raymond Chen comments that a kernel thread gets involved as well as the setter/waiter, and I'm not going to argue that one. If you want to safely 'ping-pong' two threads, I suggest two semaphores.

Comment: It's not like there's a dedicated thread for managing events. The kernel runs on all threads. (Even in the case of two threads, you might not be okay, because thread B might manage to wait on the event *before* thread A gets woken. For example, maybe thread A got hijacked by a kernel APC and is unable to service the event for a while.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I got the picture.

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondChen - I'll stick to semaphores.  At least Windows thread synchro does not support the 'spurious wakeup' feature of some other OS...